# Set build timestamp enviromental variable in docker compose or DockerFile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

TL;DR
Is there a way to set an env variable which inside docker-compose or DockerFile which will represent the build time (the build time from the machine the build runs on)?

I have a daily build, and I need to set the build timestamp inside the GUI, currently, the GUI gets the version+timestamp from an env variable.

I would like to set the version timestamp inside the DockerFile / docker-compose for it to change when the build accrues, I've tried a few things, none of them were successfully.

Comment: By "build time" do you mean the exact time at which the `docker build` command constructed the image?